# Displaying an serialize array

Tags: php, sql

I have an array being collect via a form like below:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="contractors[]" >
```

Input code to save the array in the DB.

```
$options = $_POST['contractors'];  
$serializedoptions = serialize($options);
```

It saves the array in the DB in the format below, but I cannot display it properly. When I pull the entire It shows:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:28:Contractor1";i:1;s:15:"Contractor2";i:2;s:10:"Contractor3";}
```

How can I get it to display in a more readable format?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form_2 GROUP BY jobname");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th><font size='1'>Job Name</th>
<th><font size='1'>Contractors</th>
<th><font size='1'>Notes</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['jobname'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['contractors'] . "</font></td>";
  echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['notes'] . "</font></td>";

  echo "</tr>";

  }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That which is serialized must be unserialized. Just use the `unserialize` function on the data before working with it. In your case, an array will be returned.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

```
$options = unserialize($serializedoptions);
```

Other languages can unserialize PHP `serialize()` as well if you find supporting code for it. For example, here is one for JavaScript: http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/

**EDIT:**

Updating the code you added, you can display it like any other PHP variable once you unserialize the value.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['jobname'] . "</font></td>";
    echo "<td><font size='1'>";
    $contractors = unserialize($row['contractors']);
    foreach ($contractors as $contractor)
        echo htmlspecialchars($contractor).'<br/>';
    echo "</font></td>";
    echo "<td><font size='1'>" . $row['notes'] . "</font></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I have edited my question to be more detailed. How do I unsterilize?

Comment: I added a code example. Tip: Be sure to escape your HTML with `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `print_r` on the unserialized array:

```
print_r(unserialize($serializedArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unserialize command.  You can then echo it using var_dump() or print_r().

In the HTML Table above, you would have to further break down the result for $row['contractors'].

So first, you would unserialize that value, so lets say

$contractors = unserialize($row['contractors']);

Then you can iterate through the new array of $contractors, and echoing a 
 after each one, all inside the same TD.

I can't actually unserialize the above serialized data, so I can't write the loop for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `unserialize($serializedoptions)` to convert it back into an array. If you want to view it, use `var_dump($unserialized)`